# Updating button text on GUI from within runspace

Tags: powershell, winforms, user-interface, runspace

Lately I've been messing around with WinForms GUI run in its own runspace. What I'm trying to accomplish is to Update text property of button via click event of another button. Code seen below.

```
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})

$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash) 
         
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({ 
  
$syncHash.main2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$syncHash.main2.Icon = $icon3
$syncHash.main2.ClientSize = '220,200'
$syncHash.main2.MinimizeBox = $false
$syncHash.main2.MaximizeBox = $false
$syncHash.main2.Text = 'Options'  
$syncHash.main2.AutoSize = $false  
$syncHash.main2.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$syncHash.main2.TopMost = $true
 
$syncHash.label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$syncHash.label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$syncHash.label1.Text = 'Button Name'
$syncHash.label1.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$syncHash.label1.TextAlign = 'MiddleCenter'
$syncHash.label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
 
$syncHash.label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$syncHash.label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,41)
$syncHash.label2.Text = $settings.buttons.1
$syncHash.label2.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$syncHash.label2.TextAlign = 'MiddleCenter'
$syncHash.label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)

$syncHash.label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$syncHash.label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,71)
$syncHash.label3.Text = $settings.buttons.2
$syncHash.label3.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$syncHash.label3.TextAlign = 'MiddleCenter'
$syncHash.label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
 
$syncHash.label4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$syncHash.label4.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(111,10)
$syncHash.label4.Text = 'Text to Copy'
$syncHash.label4.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$syncHash.label4.TextAlign = 'MiddleLeft'
$syncHash.label4.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)

$syncHash.label5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$syncHash.label5.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(111,41)
$syncHash.label5.Text = $settings.Text.1
$syncHash.label5.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$syncHash.label5.Multiline = $true
$syncHash.label5.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
 
$syncHash.label6 = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]::new()
$syncHash.label6.Location = [System.Drawing.Point]::new(111,71)
$syncHash.label6.BorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$syncHash.label6.Text = [PSCredential]::new(0, ($settings.Text.2|ConvertTo-SecureString)).GetNetworkCredential().Password
$syncHash.label6.Multiline = $true
$syncHash.label6.Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(100,30)
 
$syncHash.button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$syncHash.button1.Text = 'Save'
$syncHash.button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (10,101)
$syncHash.button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,30)
 
$syncHash.button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$syncHash.button2.Text = 'Close'
$syncHash.button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point (111,101)
$syncHash.button2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,30)




$button1.Add_Click({


$syncHash.button2.Text = "ASD"

})

$syncHash.button2.Add_Click({
$syncHash.main2.Close()|out-null
})

$syncHash.main2.Controls.AddRange(@(
$syncHash.label1, 
$syncHash.label2, 
$syncHash.label3, 
$syncHash.label4, 
$syncHash.label5, 
$syncHash.label6,
$syncHash.button1, 
$syncHash.button2)) 
$syncHash.main2.ShowDialog()
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

This does nothing in the runspace.

```
$syncHash.button2.Text = "ASD"
```

However, if I run a version of the code, where no synchronised hashtable is used and avery object is saved in ot's own variable (i.e `$main2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form` instead of `$syncHash.main2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form`). Button Click works and the text changes. What's more frustrationg is that if I update `$syncHash.button2.Text` from outside of runspace (i.e. from terminal in ISE) it magically works. Please help

[EDIT] I tried using a function that uses `[ref]` accelerator, hoping it would update the value, but that also does nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724246/runspace-for-button-event-in-powershell/72724752#72724752

Comment: Yes and no. You solutions shows me how to accomplish what I want, just not the way I wanted it.  Thank you

Comment: Recommendation is to run GUI app in the main thread and actions / event handlers in a separated runspace, seem to be opposed as what you're doing